# Displaying an array with a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display information I received from a class I created called cardbox, there are six of them, and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I think it is where I created dogbreed it doesn't see it as an array but idk any help would be appreciated.

```
var dogNames = document.getElementsByClassName("cardbox-header");
var dogBreed = document.getElementsByClassName("content-breed");
var textBreed = "<ul>";
var breed;

//Look for Males in the array with the cardbox gender and breed descriptions
for(var k=0;k<dogBreed.length;k++)
{
    breed = dogBreed.substring(0,4);
    if (breed == "Male")
    {
        textBreed += "<li>" + dogNames[k].textContent + "</li>";
    }
    else
    {
        textBreed += "<li>" + dogNames[k].textContent + "</li>";
    }
}

textBreed += "/ul";

// THE CODE FOR DISPLAYING A LIST OF MALE DOGS
document.getElementById("info-maleDogs").innerHTML = textBreed;

//THE CODE FOR DISPLAYING A LIST OF FEMALE DOGS
document.getElementById("info-femaleDogs").innerHTML = textBreed;
```

Comment: `textBreed += "/ul";` is not closing the list correctly and `breed = dogBreed.substring(0,4);` does not include the array index `k` nor any sort of value. Check your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code, I added another array that stores the gender of the dogs. Took away the female part and wrote that into its own code but it's a copy of what I'm going to show and then changed the display code.

```
var genderCells=[];
var l=0;
for(var k=0;k<dogBreed.length;k++)
{
    genderCells[l] = dogBreed[k].textContent.substring(0,4);
    if (genderCells[l] == "Male")
    {
        textBreedM += "<li>" + dogNames[k].textContent + "</li>";
        document.getElementById("info-maleDogs").innerHTML = textBreedM;
        l++;
    }
}


textBreedM += "/ul";
```